# What is the equivalent of Android okhttp in iOS?

Tags: android, ios, nsurlconnection, okhttp

Android Source

```
String url = "http://www.example.com";
OkHttpClient client = clientBuilder.build();
Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(url)
                    .addHeader("Host", "api.example.com")
                    .addHeader("Referer", "http://www.examplegood.com/")
                    .build();

Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

It works well. I tried in iOS using NSURLConnection request.

iOS Source

```
NSString *url = @"http://www.example.com";
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setValue:@"api.example.com" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Host"];
[request setValue:@"http://www.examplegood.com/" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Referer"];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
[request setHTTPMethod: @"GET"];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                NSMutableData *result = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
                [result appendData:data];

                NSString* resultStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:result encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                NSLog(@"result:%@",resultStr);
            }];
```

It works bad. There is no response.
What is the equivalent of Android OkHttpClient newCall() in iOS?

Comment: Have you disabled App Transport Security?  You should check the `error` value that is passed to your completion handler.  Chances are it says "The resource could not be loaded because the App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure connection"

Comment: There is no problem at App Transport Security.

Comment: Have you checked `error`?  If I use a https url then your code works for me with `https://www.google.com`

Comment: I change url to `https://www.google.com`, Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1011 "Request failed: not found (404)" UserInfo={com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.response=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x17d24280> { URL: https://www.google.com/ } { status code: 404, headers {
    "Content-Length" = 1561;
    "Content-Type" = "text/html; charset=UTF-8";
    Date = "Tue, 31 May 2016 01:04:05 GMT";
} }

Comment: So it works.  You have a bad URL somewhere so you got a 404. Also be aware that `initWithData:result encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding` can return `nil` if the data can't be decoded using `NSUTF8StringEncoding`.  You can try `NSASCIIStringEncoding`

Comment: You should set a breakpoint on the first line of your completion handler block and step through; try and see what is happening

Comment: Also, how come your logs show alamofire.  Your question doesn't show anything to do with AFNetworking

Comment: This is my code that successfully retrieves the Google home page - https://gist.github.com/paulw11/d2de0e79d29fc7e031d10e413215eb90

Comment: `https://www.google.com` works good. But my url is no response and no error. just loading page... so long time.. and return empty.

Comment: So that indicates that what you are sending to your server isn't what it wants. What error do you get?  A timeout? Without providing more information on your actual server there isn't much more anyone can do.  Can you check your server logs?

Comment: request url is not my server.  I think that my error is timeout.

Comment: Why are you connecting to one hostname and providing a different hostname in the Host header?  I'm pretty sure the URL loading system in iOS/OS X explicitly does not let you override the Host header unless you provide an IP address in the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem using NSURLConnection. And get response data by this delegate.

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
```

Comment: Can you show your code for the http request?  I know its been a few years but I am having the same issue